# How can I update AssemblyVersion number in AssemblyInfo.cs with build number of Azure DevOps via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I want to update my version number in AssemblyInfo.cs with the build number of Azure DevOps (VSTS).

Does anyone know how I can do that through PowerShell?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to do it is with [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task) Extension, and use the variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)` in the version field.

But if you want to use your own PowerShell script you can do it with this script:

```
$buildNumber = "$env:Build_BuildNumber"
$pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
$AssemblyFiles = Get-ChildItem . AssemblyInfo.cs -rec

foreach ($file in $AssemblyFiles)
{

(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -match $pattern){
        '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("{0}")]' -f $buildNumber
    } else {
        # Output line as is
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $file.PSPath

}
```

Comment: I usually recommend GitVersion so "best way" is a bit too opinionated IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing the GitVersionTask nuget package - this will generate a version number based on the number of commits since your previous build automatically, and update AssemblyVersion and the BuildNumber for you.

https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion